# Ray plane intersection finding direction vector

Tags: c++, vector, geometry, raytracing, plane

I'm required to calculate the intersection point of a light ray and a plane,
I'm given the following-
normal vector to the plane, a point on the plane, my light source point in space 
and thats it.
now I know that in order to calculate the intersection point I need the directional vector V from the light source towards the intersection point but I have no idea how I can find it since usually in order to find the directional vector I would calculate 
V = (intersectionPoint - sourcePoint)
but this time I dont have the intersection point...
(to make it more understandable , I have - P0, N, Q0, trying to get V and P.

[image]

thanks in advance !

Comment: You do not have enough information. Rays from the light source could intersect anywhere on the plane so there is no way of finding P or V.

Comment: You are correct I was missing some given info that allows me to calculate V , thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the ray is perpendicular to the plane, otherwise your question does not make much sense. If this is the case, then V = +/- N.

The points **P** which lay in the plane all satisfy the equation:

< **P**, **N**> = <**Q0**, **N**>

Where <,> denotes the dot product.

On the other hand, a point on the ray satisfy the equation:

**P** = **P0** + *t* **N**

For some real value of *t*.

Combining the two you get for *t*:

*t* = < **N** , **Q0** - **P0** > / < **N**, **N** >

The sign of *t* determines **V**:

**V** = sign(*t*) **N**

You get the intersection point **P** by reusing the ray equation:

**P** = **P0** + *t* **N**

Comment: can you please explain why does the vector V must be perpendicular to the plane ? as far as I know it does not have to be (but I might be wrong) , all I know is that the equation t=<N,Q0-P0>/<N,V> is correct but I dont see how I can substitute V for N in the denominator

Comment: It doesn't, that's why he/she said "assume". This assumption selects the "fastest ray" to get to the plane (or the "first one" from P0 if you will), assuming your light source is isotropic.